# how to display osd_cat on a remote HDMI Screen

Tags: ssh, x11, xorg

i have installed xosd an used osd_cat to display text in my screen. the problem is that i cant do it on the remote station on the remote screen through SSH.

**I want to execute osd_cat on the remote HDMI Screen connected to the raspberry pi, not on my SSH screen**

i tried

```
 export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

and

adding `DISPLAY=:0.0` before the command

but it didn't work

**FIY:**

when i use xrandr it gives me this:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1027 X 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768     0.0*
```

Comment: Does X11 forwarding work for other applications? Here `osd_cat` works out of the box without messing with the `DISPLAY` variable.

Comment: I want to execute osd_cat on the remote HDMI Screen connected to the raspberry pi, not on my SSH screen